# How to write the difference formula for Linear Mixed Effects Models (with lmertest or lme4)?

Tags: r, lme4

I have a training dataset with:

```
$ NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON       : Factor w/ 9 levels "8647","8666",..: 3 4 5 8 9 1 2 3 4 6 ...
$ TEMPERATURE_AIR            : num  6.29 6.13 6 7.05 8.16 ...
$ MonthNumber                : Factor w/ 12 levels "1","2","3","4",..: 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 1
$ HOURS                      : Factor w/ 24 levels "0","1","2","3",..: 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 .
$ TEMPERATURE_COUPON         : num  5.1 6.6 4.5 5.4 4.7 ...
```

My best ANOVA model is with interactions on variables :

```
 lm(TEMPERATURE_COUPON ~ TEMPERATURE_AIR * MonthNumber * HOURS, ...)
```

So now I want to improve my model by using Linear Mixed Effects Models (NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON).

I want to study all randoms effects for NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON, both for intercept and the covariables.
But I'm not sure to correctly write the formula and understand it.

Are theses formula valables?

Model without intercept + slope :

```
lmerTest::lmer(TEMPERATURE_COUPON ~ TEMPERATURE_AIR * MonthNumber * HOURS + 
(1 +  TEMPERATURE_AIR | NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON) +
(1 +  MonthNumber | NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON) +
(1 +  HOURS | NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON) +
```

Model with intercept + slope :

```
merTest::lmer(TEMPERATURE_COUPON ~ TEMPERATURE_AIR * MonthNumber * HOURS + 
(0 +  TEMPERATURE_AIR | NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON) +
(0 +  MonthNumber | NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON) +
(0 +  HOURS | NUM_DEVICE_ID_COUPON) +
```

What additional formulas can I test please?
Thanks.
Théo.

Comment: How does this question differ from [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71371765/strategy-to-study-random-effects-with-package-lme4-or-lmertest) ?

Comment: And have you looked at https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#model-specification ?